# Getting exception as "Collection was mutated while being enumerated"

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am getting the Collection was mutated while being enumerated exception when I am using this code can any one suggest me how to get out of this.

```
PaymentTerms * currentElement;
for (currentElement in termsArray)
{
    printf("\n currentElement Value........%s",[currentElement.days UTF8String]);
    printf("\n Str value...%s",[Str UTF8String]);
    NSRange range = [currentElement.days rangeOfString:Str options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if(!(range.location != NSNotFound))
    {
        PaymentTerms *pTerm1 = [[PaymentTerms alloc]init];
        pTerm1.days = Str;
        printf("\n  pTerm1.days...%s",[ pTerm1.days UTF8String]);
        [termsArray addObject:pTerm1];
    }   
}
```

Hope I get quick response from ur side.
Thank in advance,
Monish.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot change array while you're enumerating it. As a workaround you should accumulate new objects in temporary array and add them after enumeration:

```
PaymentTerms * currentElement;
NSMutableArray* tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (currentElement in termsArray)
{
    NSRange range = [currentElement.days rangeOfString:Str options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if(!(range.location != NSNotFound))
    {
       PaymentTerms *pTerm1 = [[PaymentTerms alloc]init];
       pTerm1.days = Str;
       [tempArray addObject:pTerm1];
       [pTerm1 release];
    }   
}
[termsArray addObjectsFromArray: tempArray];
```

P.S. do not forget to release pTerm1 object you create - your code contains memory leak

In respond to poster's comment (and actual task) - I think the easiest way to make bool flag indicating if day value was found in cycle. If not - add new object after cycle ends:

```
PaymentTerms * currentElement;
BOOL dayFound = NO;
for (currentElement in termsArray)
{
    NSRange range = [currentElement.days rangeOfString:Str options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if(range.location != NSNotFound)
        dayFound = YES;
}
if (!dayFound)
     // Create and add new object here
```

Comment: Thanks for your useful code.but I got one more problem.Actually the thing is I need to check the string the array if it is not present I have to add it to the array list.Now the problem is I had 3 Items in my list which is not equal to the string I am searching for so It was adding the object 3 times instead of 1 time.Is there any other suggestions for this.

Comment: You don't need to release tempArray here because you never take ownership of it.  Also, `!(range.location != NSNotFound)` is the same as `(range.location == NSNotFound)`.

Comment: @vodkhang, no doing so you'll just add a new element if any of objects in termsArray has day property different from Str

Comment: ops, damn it. It is a stupid mistake:). Your new one is the correct one

Comment: if he doesn't want to copy values in a new array (for example when using large arrays to avoid wasting memory) he can simply use a standard for loop

Answer (score 2):

This line   `[termsArray addObject:pTerm1];` 
 will throw that exception. You CANNOT add/delete an element from an array inside a for each loop.    `for (currentElement in termsArray)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes...we cannot enumerate while the array is getting updated...This might be irritating for the programmers who are from ActionScript background.Some times things go worse like "You even dont get a crash or intimation at runtime when you update an array count while it is being enumerated"-The execution just behaves abnormally at that time.

Btw you can go for this type of implementation where you can have minor changes to your code.

```
 for (int i=0 ; i< termsArray.count ;i++)  //counting termsArray on every iteration
 {
  id currentElement  = [ termsArray objectAtIndex:i];
  ......
  .....
 }
```

Of-course,This(i< termsArray.count) might seem bad as we are calculating the count for every iteration...And thats the trick here to have minor changes.But I would strongly recommend VLADIMIR's implementation as its clear for reading.

Answer (score 0):

you are adding an object to your collection as you are looping over it, thats whats causing the error. your `if` statement is nested inside the `for`

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you are adding new objects to termsArray within the for loop

- Create a new empty array (e.g.newTermsArray)
- In the first loop create and add these new items to newTermsArray
- Then you will need a second loop to add the items from newTermsArray back into the original termsArray

Answer (score 0):

Just dealt with the same bug in a rather complex app. The solution is simple - create a copy and work with the copy of array (and remove it from the original if you want. Then discard the copy.

```
for(CharacterModelNode* node in self.allPlayers)
{
   // Some operation that may mutate allPlayers (ex: player dies from poison damage and is removed from this array at some other part of an app)

}

//workaround in some cases - create a copy of array and run operations that can kill player on this array (it will not be mutated anywhere else in the app

NSArray* allPlayersCopy = [self.allPlayers copy];

for(CharacterModelNode* node in allPlayersCopy)
{
    [node.character refreshBuffs];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

use try and catch for handling exception in nsmutable array

```
@try {
    //code for accessing element.

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {


       /// show exception here

    }
```

Comment: This does not answer OP's question. Please reread the question and consider @Vladimir's answer.