# what's reason for this error?

Tags: iphone

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x175800> was mutated while being enumerated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting exception as "Collection was mutated while being enumerated"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424861/getting-exception-as-collection-was-mutated-while-being-enumerated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You changed a mutable array while you were iterating over it.  You can't do that.  One solution might be to iterate over a copy of the array, but it really depends on what you are doing.

Comment: -(IBAction)getCameraPicture:(id)sender
{
 UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 picker.delegate = self;
// picker.allowsImageEditing = NO;
 picker.sourceType = (sender == takePictureButton) ? UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera :
 UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
 [self presentModalViewController: picker animated:YES];
 [picker release];
}
 i got error in this camera button action  error

Comment: If you have a new question, you should post it as a new question, not a comment on an answer.

Answer (score -1):

This error usually occurs when u r trying to mutate an array while using fast enumeration. Either use the traditional for loop.. or tag the obj tht u want to mutate.. and do it after the you are done with the enumeration.